# Create graphical editor using with multiple language plugins

Tags: java, dsl, xtext, emf

I'm using Xtext, EMF, GMF and EuGeNia to develop my development interface. I have a bunch of plugins, those plugins inherits from an single xtext project, "core".
This core project describes common elements and statements in all the languages covered in the IDE. My question is:

I need to create an graphical editor, some kind of flow control graphic, that generate compilable code, I found an example using an single xtext project and an single ecore project. But how can I make the graphical editor using multiple Xtext projects using multiple ecore files?